# Why is my mirror only reflecting things that are close to it?

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, eevee-render-engine

[image]

I am trying to render out a scene of a bathroom. I am attempting to make a mirror material. It doesn't reflect anything that isn't very very close to it. I made a cube and put an array modifier on it and colored it blue to see how far the falloff went. As you can see it doesn't render all the cubes. Also for some reason, it reflects the front face on the cube closest to it as grey.

My node set up is not convoluted. It is simply the Principled Shader, but with adjusted settings, as you can see below. I would like the mirror to act as a mirror in real life as much as possible. I am using Eevee and I need to stay in Eevee for my purposes.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eevee has its limitations, thankfully there is an easy solution:

1. Shift + A -> Light Probe -> Reflection Plane
2. Move and scale the Reflection Plane to fit the mirrored surface
3. Center the Reflection Plane on the mirror, then nudge it forward slightly

That's it. Enjoy!

Comment: So this worked, almost. I will mark it as correct since it did the minimum if what I wanted. It doesn't display the materials that I have made in a more complex node set up as grey